# Rails : How to assign a ruby parameter in hidden_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get the id of the current object I'm working with like this:

--- In my view ----

```
*<%= hidden_field_tag(:id, Report.find(params[:id])) %>

<%= submit_tag "Send report by mail ", :class => "btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block"%>*
```

--- In my controller ----

```
@report = Report.find(params[:id])
```

But I got the error,

```
Couldn't find Report with id=# Report:0x007f90e82d2640>
```

Can anyone help ??
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I see you've written

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:id, Report.find(params[:id])) %>
```

First thing here is you are setting object `Report.find(params[:id])` will return an object `Report:0x007f90e82d2640` that you are setting for id, so that's exactly what you are getting in controller in params. And your query tries to search reports with id `Report:0x007f90e82d2640`, which will obviously fail, and gives u an error.

Secondly, you are querying database directly from view, which is not a good practice and is against Rails way of separation of concerns.

You must set an object with Required report object in the action which is rendering this view,

Say, in controller:

`@report = Report.find(params[:id])`

and then in your view :

`<%= hidden_field(:id, @report.id) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is this

`View`

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "id", '3'%>
```

`Controller`

```
Report.find(params["id"])
```

What you have written is

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:id, Report.find(params[:id])) %>
```

`Report.find(params[:id]))` will return an object not id of the object.
And you require ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value in the hidden field:

`<%= hidden_field_tag(:id, value=(Report.find(params[:id])).id)%>`